# How can i add diffrents images in javascipt

Tags: javascript

i have this code but im stuck how can i set different photo for each book because in this function i can set only the same photo

```js
const books = [{
    title: "book1",
    author: "x"
  },
  {
    title: "book2",
    author: "y"

  },
  {
    title: "book3",
    author: "z"
  }
];
myfunction(books);

function myfunction(books) {
  let content = document.querySelector("#content");
  let list = content.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    let item = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
    let book = item.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    book.innerHTML = books[i].title + '-' + books[i].author + '<br><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">';

  }
}
```

```html
<div id='content'></div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're newbie in coding. You should understand all one of your lines of what you're code and try to invent answer to any task by yourself even if it looks like impossible. Have a good luck!

```js
const books = [{
    title: "book1",
    author: "x",
    img: "https://example.com/img1.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "book2",
    author: "y",
    img: "https://example.com/img2.jpg"

  },
  {
    title: "book3",
    author: "z",
    img: "https://example.com/img3.jpg"
  }
];
myfunction(books);

function myfunction(books) {
  let content = document.querySelector("#content");
  let list = content.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    let item = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
    let book = item.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    book.innerHTML = books[i].title + '-' + books[i].author + '<br><img src="' + books[i].img + '">';

  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: *"You're newbie in coding."* You don't actually have to say that. =P

Comment: @HoldOffHunger why? just facts.

Comment: Just a suggestion!  Sometimes "newbie" is interpreted negatively, like any name.  Nothing wrong with it really, just saying it's nice to be nice.

Comment: ok. I don't interprete "newbie" like that - in my native lang it means smth like just person who starts educating in something. Without negative meanings.

Answer (score 0):

One method you can do is to create an array of images of books, in which the elements are Strings of the links of the images.

```
function myfunction(books) {
  let images = ["link1","link2","link3"];
  let content = document.querySelector("#content");
  let list = content.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    let item = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
    let book = item.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    book.innerHTML = books[i].title + '-' + books[i].author + '<br><img src="' + images[i] + '">';

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add image path as property to the books object and use it as below:
Change `src` with the required path.
Here is the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for understanding javascript objects and how to access them.

```js
const books = [{
    title: "book1",
    author: "x",
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
  },
  {
    title: "book2",
    author: "y",
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/200"
  },
  {
    title: "book3",
    author: "z",
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/300"
  }
];
myfunction(books);

function myfunction(books) {
  let content = document.querySelector("#content");
  let list = content.appendChild(document.createElement('ul'));
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    let item = list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
    let book = item.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    book.innerHTML = books[i].title + '-' + books[i].author + '<br>' + '<img src="'+ books[i].src +'">';

  }
}
```

```html
<div id='content'></div>
```